# PHPExcel custom thousands delimiter

Tags: phpexcel, number-formatting, digit-separator

I need to set custom thousands separator in PHPExcel for all. According this site https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats I wrote this pattern **# ##0.00 €** and it works with thousands BUT the millions are not separated correctly. For example if input is **1 000 000 000** result is **1000000 000.00 €**. For now I made this pattern **# ### ### ### ##0.00 €** but it is not clean. Is there a way to set separator for thousands, millions .... ?

Comment: What is wrong with the pattern you are using? It's perfectly "clean" in the sense that it takes care of your requirement. Without you specifying it how is PHPExcel supposed to know what you want?

Comment: Its not clean because it does not handle bigger numbers.

Comment: According to what you can do with Excel itself in the format you desire specifying multiple `#` appears to be the only way to get the format that you want. Interestingly if you were to use a `,` (comma) you only need a minimum number of placeholders to have it format regardless of the size of the number.